# Auto generate list of dependencies from Artifactory

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, artifactory

Is there a way to auto generate list of dependencies from Artifactory, for every entry in artifactory. So I can then copy the needed entries for my projects instead of having to manually type each dependency by hand?

Comment: Why not using [maven-dependency-plugin:tree](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

Nexus, Artifactory and Archiva do not support this.

You can instead run:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

And get the dependencies for your current project.

Answer (score 0):

Artifactory is a binary repository, not a dependency manager. It barely saves the binaries and existing information about artifacts. Since we have no idea what build tool (and dependency manager) you are using, we don't know how to it generates the dependencies tree for you.
We can give you information about a passed build (which was deployed previously to Artifactory). In this case we know de-facto what was resolved. But we can't know the dependencies in front (before you ran your tool).

Answer (score 0):

seems artifactory doesn't do this, even though it knows every dependency in its repository

ie:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>group1</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

since its a 'maven' repo it knows these three things for every jar added to it.
Maven maven-dependency-plugin:tree does something different than listing all dependencies added to the repo